# How to call a function on files in different folders after getting filenames

Tags: python

I have two files in two different folders and I want to read both files one after the other to go through my python script.

```
import os

    for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):

        for file in f:
           if not file.startswith('.'):
              print(os.path.join(r, file))

    with open(<**filename**>, 'r') as f:
```

From above I can get file names printed, but I want each file to go through my function which does validation.

In place of <**filename**> I'm trying to read all files one by one which I got from above.

Comment: So, what's the question ? You can print each file you can call a function for each file as well.

Comment: I can print file names but , how do I read all files one by one.... for suppose I got 4 files from directory and I want to go through all the files. Looking for loop that goes through all files.

Answer (score 0):

To access the filenames you printed, store the filenames in a list for processing later:

```
import os

    filenames = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):

        for file in f:
           if not file.startswith('.'):
              filename = os.path.join(r, file)
              print(filename)
              filenames.append(filename)

    for filename in filenames:
       with open(filename, 'r') as f:
```

Alternatively use your validation function directly after you construct the filename:

```
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):

    for file in f:
       if not file.startswith('.'):
          filename = os.path.join(r, file)
          print(filename)
          # perform validation within the loop
          with open(filename, 'r') as f:
```

Comment: Great, working. But I want to skip the files names that starts with .* As the print filename prints entire path, startswith() function  is not working I guess

Comment: @saikiran doesn't the `if not file.startswith('.'):` line skip the these files?

Comment: Figured out Thank you :)